# step into system, CRTL functions with Eclipse in Linux

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse

I'm a whiz with Visual C++, but Linux development is new to me.  In Visual Studio, it's easy to trace into any code implemented by the C run time libraries. I just need to make sure the sources are installed and I can step right into any function I'd like -- malloc(), cout::operator<<(), whatever.

I'm trying to develop using Eclipse's C++ package. How can I step into C run time routines there? Since Linux is open-source, how do I step into operating system routines? Seems like it should e possible -- am I missing debug information, source code, or both? Something in my configuration?

I'm using Ubuntu 12.10 at the moment. I'm using g++. I believe I'm using the Eclipse build system as I never imported a makefile project; I just started with a simple "Hello World" project from the C++ project wizard in Eclipse.

**After hacking at this a bit:**

I've installed the libstdc++6-4.2-dbg package thinking it would be debug symbols for the libstdc library:

```
sudo apt-get install libstdc++6-4.2-dbg
```

I've also installed dpkg-dev, since the next step said I needed it:

```
sudo apt-get install dpkg-dev
```

I tried installing libc6 sources into a directory under my home:

```
apt-get source libc6
```

At this point, trying to step into printf() tells me that printf.c is missing. I can't step into malloc or strlen, which suggests that I don't understand how the C runtime libraries are factored in Linux. How are libc, glib, and libstdc++ different? Which packages do I need?

If I ask Eclipse to open the printf.c file I do have (at ~/eglibc-2.15/stdio-common/printf.c), it doesn't open the file (doesn't adjust the debugging window to show the source) and repaints the window that shows the error message about not being able to find the file. (Can't find a source file at "printf.c" Locate the file or edit the source lookup path to include its location.)

Comment: Which distro are you using?

Comment: What compiler are you using? That is key to answering this question.

Comment: Also, how are you compiling in Eclipse? Is it an imported make project, or are you using the internal Eclipse build system?

Comment: I've edited the question to include the details you requested.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst, as a Kernel developer on Linux, I do agree that using the individual tools separately will be a good thing to learn, and as such Basile's answer is usefuel.

However, the stepping into C runtime libraries should be equally possible with Eclipse. But just because the OS is open source doesn't mean that it supports you clambering around inside it willy nilly - in fact, you CAN NOT step into the OS itself from user-mode code. You nee KGDB (google it), and you definitely need a second computer to attach to the one being debugged, because when you step into the kernel, you will essentially lock up the machine, at the very least in the context you are stepping, but most likely also prevent other work from being done until you get back out from the kernel, so for example, if you step into `open()`, at some point the entire filesystem may well stop working altogether until you are back out of whatever lock you are holding. This wll certainly upset some software. Note that this is just an example of how things may work unexpectedly when debugging the kernel, not strictly "I've done this and it happened" - I have debugged kernels with debuggers several times, and you do have to be careful with what you do, and you certainly can not run the debugger on the same machine, as the machine STOPS when you are debugging.

Going back to the usermode, which you CAN debug via Eclipse, essentially all you need to do is install the source code for the runtime library you are interested in, and go... Same principle as on Windows with visual studio - except that nearly all software you ever run on a Linux system is available as source code. You may need to recompile some libraries with debugging symbols, and just like in Windows, you need to make sure the debugger knows how to find the source code. Everything else should be handled by the debugger in Eclipse. I spent about three years using Eclipse for both local and remote debugging, and in general, it works. There are quirks in places, but that's the case with almost any debugger.

Good luck.

Comment: Indeed, it makes sense that I wouldn't be able to step into the kernel from user mode. I agree -- I probably need to find the source and the symbols for the runtimes. Where do I find them and how do I install them? Must I build them myself to create symbols? If so, how? How do I point the Eclipse configuration at the run time sources and symbols so that it sees them?

Comment: Right, that's probbably a whole new "question and answer" in itself. I don't actually have Eclipse installed on any machine I'm using right now - I used to use it in my previous job, but that was in February.

http://askubuntu.com/questions/28372/how-do-i-get-the-source-code-of-packages-installed-through-apt-get

There is often also a "dbg" package for a given library, so you can install that along with the binaries. 

But as I said, it's rather a big subject to cover everything you need to know...

Comment: Actually, it's just the answer to this question: "How do I step into the C Runtimes source when doing development under Linux with Eclipse?"  I know that packages are installed with apt-get, but I don't know which package to install to get the symbols and the source, or how to connect it to Eclipse.  "libstdc++6-4.2-dbg" might be the right package -- or just one of the right packages -- but I don't know what it installs specifically or how to get Eclipse to add it to its source and symbol paths. After installing it, where does it land in the file system?

Comment: Right, so you need to install whatever library that you are trying to debug - since I don't know what your code looks like, I also don't know which libraries you may be using... But libstdc++ seems like a good start if you are using C++. 

Rebuild your source, and step into the function just like you would if you were stepping into one your your functions.

Comment: I'm trying to step into routines from the standard C Runtime: malloc(), strlen(), printf(). And from the standard C++ runtime: cout::operator<<(), and so on.  My code looks like any other trivial implementation of "hello world", though I've added calls to malloc(), free(), printf(), strlen(), and a couple of other functions.

After installing "libstdc++6-4.2-dbg", I don't notice a change in the behavior of "step into".

Comment: malloc, etc, are in glibc. Exactly what happens when you try to step into the functions?

Comment: Nothing: if I use gdb, "step" steps over them. If I use Eclipse, "step into (F5)" steps over them.

doing "apt-get install libc6-dbg" seems to have changed the behavior; after installing that package, Eclipse says it can't find a file named "printf.c".  That sounds promising, but I can't find the file anywhere, either, so I must still need some source code package.

Am I really meant to just guess which package to install?

Comment: So, that's about telling eclipse where your sources are. Try this link: 
http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fviews%2Fdebug%2Fref-editsourcelookup.htm

Comment: +1 for "doesn't mean that it supports you clambering around inside it willy nilly"

Answer (score -1):

First, you don't need Eclipse to develop software on Linux. You should better learn to do that with independent tools (command line) like `emacs` or `gedit` (as editor), `git` (version control), `make` (builder) which runs the `gcc` or `g++` compiler (both `gcc` & `g++` are part of GCC, the Gnu Compiler Collection).

<sup>really, you'll learn a lot more by not depending upon Eclipse; it may just hide you the real commands which are doing the job, and you should understand what they really are.</sup>

You want to pass the `-g -Wall` [options](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) to GCC. The `-g` option asks for debug information, and the `-Wall` options asks for almost all warnings. Improve your code till no warnings are given.

And the operating system is providing [syscalls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syscall) (which are operations provided by the kernel to applications; from the application's point of view, a syscall is atomic so you cannot step into it; however `strace` may show you all the syscalls done by some execution). If you wanted to step by step inside system libraries like `libc` you need the debugging variant of it (e.g. some `libc6-dbg` package). But there is usually no need to dive inside system libraries.

See http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/

Then, you will use `gdb` to debug the binary program.

So, step by step instructions inside a terminal:

- edit your source files with [emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) or [gedit](http://projects.gnome.org/gedit/)
- learn how to use [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/): for a single source C++ program compile it with `g++ -Wall -g source.cc -o progbin` and type `./progbin` in your terminal to run it. Only when the program is debugged and satisfactory would you compile it with optimizations (by giving the `-O` or `-O2` flag to `gcc` or `g++`)
- Use [gdb](http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) to debug a program (compiled with `-g`).
- for a multi-file C++ program, consider learning how to use [make](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/)
- use a version control system like [git](http://git-scm.com/)

For beginners, I suggest to avoid Eclipse, because it just hides to you what is really happening underneath (Eclipse is simply running other tools like the above commands)

Software development under Linux requires a different mindset than under Windows: you really are using your own loose combination of independent tools, so better to learn a bit each of them.

NB. to step inside "system" functions like `malloc` (which is above syscalls like `mmap`) you need the debug variant of the `libc` package with `aptitude install libc6-dbg`, and you need to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to `/usr/lib/debug` etc...

Comment: Not too sure why you've assumed I'm a beginner. While I'm new to Linux, I'm not at all new to software development. If I build from the command line with g++ and then debug with gdb, I find the step command steps over RTL functions just like Eclipse does. Your answer doesn't help.