# main() first defined here

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse

I'm trying to compile my project in Eclipse.

However, it says that the `main()` is defined more than once. I `grep`'d my project dir and it found only one definition of `main()`, in main.cpp.

Apparently it is somewhere else.maybe a dir I linked to.

The only dirs I linked to are:

```
-ljson_linux-gcc-4.5.2_libmt
```

The compiler output is:

```
make all 
Building file: ../src/main.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -Ijson_linux-gcc-4.5.2_libmt -I/usr/include/mysql -I/usr/include/jsoncpp-src-0.5.0/include -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -Ijson_linux-gcc-4.5.2_libmt -MMD -MP -MF"src/main.d" -MT"src/main.d" -o"src/main.o" "../src/main.cpp"
Finished building: ../src/main.cpp

Building target: Atms
Invoking: GCC C++ Linker
g++ -L-L/usr/include/jsoncpp-src-0.5.0/include/ -o"Atms"  ./src/atmstypes.o ./src/base64.o ./src/hregex.o ./src/libparser.o ./src/log.o ./src/main.o ./src/serv.o ./src/sqlfeeder.o ./src/teleindex.o ./src/telepipe.o ./src/telesharedobject.o ./src/treet.o ./src/ttable.o   -l-ljson_linux-gcc-4.5.2_libmt
./src/serv.o: In function `main':
/usr/include/c++/4.4/new:101: multiple definition of `main'
./src/main.o:/home/idan/workspaceCpp/Atms/Debug/../src/main.cpp:12: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l-ljson_linux-gcc-4.5.2_libmt
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Atms] Error 1
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <regex.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <string>
#include "../h/hregex.h"
using namespace std;


string s = "this and7 that";
int main(int argc,char** argv){
    cout << hregex::InitRegex() << endl;
    cout <<  hregex::CheckHostnameField(s)<< "= this and7 that" << endl;
    s = "this and7 that";
    cout <<  hregex::CheckURLField(s)<< "= this and7 that" << endl;
    s = "/lol/idan.html";
    cout <<  hregex::CheckURLField(s)<< "= /lol/idan.html" << endl;
    s = "/lol2#/idan.html";
    cout <<  hregex::CheckURLField(s)<< "= /lol2#/idan.html" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

How can I prevent the error from appearing?

Comment: does eclipse tell you where it is getting defined twice?  Anything in the output conosle?

Comment: By any chance, have you included any `.c` file in `main.c` instead of a `.h` header file ?

Comment: i guess at this point we would need to see main.cpp

Comment: The message referrnces `/usr/include/c++/4.4/new:101`. What have yoy got there?

Comment: The above error appears due to multiple definitions for a function which breaks the [One Definition Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule).

Comment: Did you consider not using Eclipse, and at least once do the compilation command yourself? You'll understand much more what is happenning. See  http://stackoverflow.com/a/14029052/841108

Answer (score 2, accepted):

g++ says serv.o has a main function.

If there actually is no main() it serv.cpp, check the includes, maybe you did a bad #include and included a .cpp instead of a .h ?

As an extra remark :
it tries to bind against the library "-ljson_linux-gcc-4.5.2_libmt"

So there is "-l-ljson_linux-gcc-4.5.2_libmt" in the link command line. Remove the -l in your configuration